# EADDRNOTAVAIL when Dockerizing Node.js app

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

With the following app, I am able to start it manually via npm install / node app.js. The issue is with trying to run the app via a Docker container.

Apart from what the rest of the app is (which doesn't matter because running the Docker container doesn't even get that far), the Dockerfile pulls the code from GitHub, switches to that directory, then runs app.js (which pulls the host and port from a config.json file). Attempting to run the container with the IP address of the server (what it should be listening on) results in the following error:

```
uncaughtException: Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL
Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL
at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1024:19)
at listen (net.js:1065:10)
at net.js:1147:9
at dns.js:72:18
at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:929:3
```

Changing the port does nothing to resolve the issue. I've included the relevant files below (with certain sections replaced with {pseudocode}). Any help would be *immensely* appreciated, because I'm absolutely hopeless when it comes to Docker.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM    centos:centos6
RUN     rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
RUN     yum install -y npm git
RUN git clone {repo.git}
COPY . /src
RUN npm install
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

config.json:

```
{
    "app_host": "{IP of server}",
    "app_port": "20000"
}
```

app.js:

```
var server = app.listen(config_json.app_port, config_json.app_host, function () {

  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('\n  listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);

});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Have you tried to hardcode the port and IP address in the call to app.listen to see if there's an issue with reading the config?

Comment: It's able to read the config, the rest of the log output states the variables from the config.json (including the ones I removed). And, if I pass the IP as something like 0.0.0.0, it says listening on 0.0.0.0:20000.

I've also tried hardcoding it just to see if maybe it would fix it, and it ran into the same error, unfortunately.

Comment: To what _is_ `app_host` set to? Is it an IP-address that is valid in your Docker container? I believe that Docker uses a private IP range for its interfaces so you cannot bind to an "outside" IP number directly.

Comment: what command do you use to run the container?

Comment: @robertklep it's set to the private IP of the server. Like I said, I'm useless with Docker, so I had no idea I couldn't do that.

Comment: @Thomasleveil I've tried doing it as part of the Docker build (basically replacing the CMD at the end with RUN node app.js) and I've run it with `docker run -p 20001:20000 container-name`. Both ways result in the error.

Comment: @JackHilary I would think it should work using `0.0.0.0` as `app_host` and running Docker with `-p` to map an "external" port to the "internal" one.

Comment: Make sure port 20001 is not already in use on the Docker host. You might already have a running container mapped to that port, use `docker ps`

Comment: @JackHilary have you made any progress?

Comment: @Thomasleveil Was in the process of posting here. Fixed it, the issue was explicitly declaring the IP address. Not declaring it, letting it automatically get set to 0.0.0.0, and binding the exposed port to an outside port fixed it. Site is up and running.

Is there a way to close/answer my own question? I'm new to actually asking a question here.

Comment: You should then answer your own question with details that will help others who have the same issue. And accept your own answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out robertklep in the comments to my question was correct: the issue was trying to explicitly pass the IP of the server into app.js. That's the way the app was configured to work just by itself with Node, but that can't be done with Docker.

The only code change needed was removing `config_json.app_host` from `app.listen` in app.js. Then, running the container by binding the exposed port to any available port on the server causes it to work.